# Windows 8 task manager: single-core CPU graph only?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager, multi-core

On multi-core CPU systems, Windows 7's task manager used to display a separate utilization graph for each core unit:

[image: Windows 7 task manager]

On Windows 8 the task manager looks much fancier, and yet it shows a single graph for a multi-core cpu and there is no obvious way to show other cores:

[image]

Did Microsoft remove this feature or is it buried somewhere in the settings?

**Update:** Okay, it's really that simple. It turned out that I could not switch the graph into multi-core mode as the 'logical processors' menu item was disabled. Disabled because I was running Windows 8 in a virtual machine that by default had limited the number of available processors to 1. After changing the setting and rebooting I've got new graph options. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To see individual graphs, **"Change graph to" > "Logical processors"**

[image]

The task manager can also show a **heat map** of the cores to better show what they are doing (instead of having tiny graphs). This means that if you have a large number of cores (eg. 160), it will be easier to interpret the data:

[image]

More tips on using the task manager can be found at [8 Windows 8 Task Manager Tips](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/8-windows-8-task-manager-tips/)

Sources:

- http://www.thewindowsclub.com/configure-windws-8-multi-core-support
- http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/8-windows-8-task-manager-tips/
- http://www.tomshardware.com/news/windows-8-task-manager-logical-cores-hyperthreading-win8,13848.html
- http://www.extremetech.com/computing/102207-windows-8-task-manager-good-news-if-you-have-more-than-1-cpu

Comment: Thanks, @ronalchn. It turned out I had 1 core in the first place (Virtual machine). I have updated the question with the explanation.

Comment: Just curious, but how do you have 8 Physical Processors running on (what seems to be) a regular windows 8 system? Assuming you're not using Server 2012 then doesn't the maximum amount of physical processors cap out at 2?

Comment: @BenFranchuk money. And lots of it.

Comment: @hunterboerner that's the truth.

Comment: Damn. I want this machine.

Answer (score 2):

right click roughly where "cpu" is shown. a submenu opens, then you click "change graph" to show "logical processors".

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following steps to see in an alternative way
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Or start the Resource Monitor by opening the [Run dialog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command#Accessing_the_Run_command) and entering [`resmon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor#Ways_to_start_the_application).