# CPU sometimes hangs at 50% maximum on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, cpu

Recently I installed Windows 8 on my HP ProBook 6450b and it appears I've got problems when using more than one program at once. Sometimes, when I run multiple programs at once, CPU hangs at 49% and never goes up. I suspect it has something to do with CPU throttling, because sometimes it just goes over 49%. I've got my notebook connected to charger and my plan is set to "Active cooling".

The weird thing is that this happens only occasionally. I found nothing in my BIOS that could change this kind of things.

Comment: You're running one core flat out.

Comment: I'd say both cores are on 50%

Comment: Unplug and run on battery until you're down to 20% or so.

Comment: Daniel, I think you get it, I just tried it and it goes slow (50%) until I reach 50% on AC or so. Maybe just a coincidence, maybe not

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the power controller suspects that the battery is dead/missing, and so throttles the CPU.  When the battery is removed from a laptop generally it will run slower, since the system depends on the battery for "peak" power.  But if you rarely run the system on battery only the charge controller loses track of the battery charge state.  Running several "deep" discharge/recharge cycles will often clear up this problem if it's simply due to the charge monitor circuitry getting confused.

Comment: Well, I run very often only on battery as I use my notebook in class

Answer (score 0):

I've lookup your [CPU model](http://ark.intel.com/products/49020/) and it appears to have 2 cores. If an application is doing a CPU intensive task on 1 thread it will use only 1 core which is +/- 50% of your CPU capacity. In taskmanager you can change the graph to [show a graph for each core](https://superuser.com/a/493831/4162).

This is not an indication that your device has problems executing more than one program at once.

Comment: I've seen this question. Every core is using 50% at max. Sometimes, it limits CPU usage at 60%, sometimes 70%.